# Show UIAlertController from inputView

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

I switched from `UIAlertView` to the iOS 8 `UIAlertController`. The switch introduced a new problem:

- I have a view with a `UITextField` with a custom `inputView`.
- While the `UITextField` is first responder, and the `inputView` is visible, I present the `UIAlertController` (in some validation condition)
- The `UIAlertController` is being presented by the view controller which owns the `inputView` view with `presentViewController:animated:completion:`
- The problem is that the alert does not show up

I'm rather confused on which view controller I should present a `UIAlertController` on, as there always could already exist a view controller that is being presented.

Comment: Do you by any chance see a warning in the console, saying "Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged"?

Comment: No, I see the following message: "Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x799a7b40> on <RangePickerViewController: 0x7b038700> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!". Also the `inputView` gets dismissed (which is owned by the RangePickerViewController).

Comment: That could point to the problem. Have you made sure that RangePickerViewController.view is added as a subview?

Comment: No I did not, as its view is the `inputView`. Maybe I rather should present the alert from the viewcontroller containing the textfield? I'll try that.

Comment: Yes, I would try that.